# Testing simple GET request using Axios and Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, axios, jestjs

I'm using `axios` `0.18.0`, `jest` `22.4.2` and I'm trying to test a simple request using Axios and Jest based on the [Axios documentation example](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/all/index.html) and [Jest Async / Await documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await)

```
// services.js
import axios from 'axios';

export const getUser = () => axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mzabriskie');


// services.spec.js
import { getUser } from './services';

it('should return data from github user', async () => {
  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
  const result = await getUser();
  console.log('RESULT -->', result);
});
```

Once the `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` is passed (in this example 30 seconds), the test gives the following error message:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout 
specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

And it never reaches the `console.log` statement.

Any idea what I might be missing here or how to debug this?

Comment: This really isn't a unit test, though. The example test is actually testing that GitHub works, not your component. You might look at `axios-mock-adapter` which is extremely useful and easy to mock out the endpoints you're trying to test. https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

Comment: You are right, but I usually test the real request in order to assure that everything is working fine and once that works I add the mock for intercepting the request (I usually use nock for this). Thanks for the suggestion in any case, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was using the dependency [jest-mock-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) which it seems once it's configured it never allows HTTP requests to go through in the tests, even if you are not using it in a specific test (like in the original question example).

So in order to fix this all related requests tests must have defined mocks in order to work (or else remove the [jest-mock-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) dependency entirely if you wish to test real API requests).